# QIcon not showing in QToolBar

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qtoolbar, qicon

I'm a beginner in Qt, currently reading this : https://zetcode.com/gui/qt5/menusandtoolbars/

When I declare QActions in a QToolBar, the QPixmap objects (turned into QIcons) are not showing :

[No icons, only text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snr4j.png)

However, the QPixmap images are actually showing when I declare a QMenu without the toolbar.

I am using Qt6 ; working on Fedora ; no warning shown on my compiler.

### simple_menu.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef SIMPLE_MENU_HPP
#define SIMPLE_MENU_HPP

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>

class SimpleMenu : public QMainWindow
{
    public:
    SimpleMenu(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};

#endif
```

### simple_menu.cpp

```cpp
#include "simple_menu.hpp"

#include <QMenu>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QAction>

SimpleMenu::SimpleMenu(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent) 
{
    QPixmap newpix("new.png");
    QPixmap openpix("open.png");

    QToolBar *toolbar = addToolBar("main toolbar");
    toolbar->addAction(QIcon(newpix), "New File");
    toolbar->addAction(QIcon(openpix), "Open File");
}
```

### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "simple_menu.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    SimpleMenu window;

    window.resize(350, 250);
    window.setWindowTitle("Tuto Toolbar");
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the system cannot find your pictures. Please try to put the full file path (like :).

```
QPixmap newpix("c:\mydoc\pictures\new.png");
```

To check if the pictures are loaded, you can do something a bit different :

```
   QPixmap newpix;
   qDebug() << newpix.load("c:\mydoc\pictures\new.png");
```

the [load](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#load) method returns true or false in case of loading fail.

Anyway, if you want to embed your icons in the final EXE file, check the [Qt resource system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

It's a convenient system to achieve what you want to do, and to avoid dealing with storage paths on your local drives.

Good luck !